# How to create nested li-ul-li elements

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested-lists

I am looking to take the following json:

```
{
   "comments":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "comment":"asdasdasdasdsadsaasd",
         "author":"Adam",
         "post_id":126,
         "ancestry":null,
         "created_at":"2014-06-18T00:25:04.421Z",
         "updated_at":"2014-06-18T00:25:04.421Z",
         "children":[
            {
               "id":4,
               "comment":"asdasdasdasdsadsaasd",
               "author":"Adam",
               "post_id":126,
               "ancestry":"3",
               "created_at":"2014-06-18T00:25:57.913Z",
               "updated_at":"2014-06-18T00:25:57.913Z",
               "children":[
                  {
                     "id":7,
                     "comment":"asdasdasdasdsadsaasd",
                     "author":"Adam",
                     "post_id":126,
                     "ancestry":"3/4",
                     "created_at":"2014-06-18T00:57:36.277Z",
                     "updated_at":"2014-06-18T00:57:36.277Z",
                     "children":[

                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "id":5,
                     "comment":"asdasdasdasdsadsaasd",
                     "author":"Adam",
                     "post_id":126,
                     "ancestry":"3/4",
                     "created_at":"2014-06-18T00:26:12.017Z",
                     "updated_at":"2014-06-18T00:26:12.017Z",
                     "children":[

                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Which could have many more children or comments nested as you see and write a recursive function that does two things:

- Walks through each of the comments blogs looking for `children`, from there walk through those - repeating till it his dead end (the function should be recursive - see what I have so far below)
- For each child in `children` and their associated child and so on and so forth, the elements should have a class of `nested` which then allows me to do something like:

  .nested .nested .nested .nested { /* css rules here for 4 levels of nesting */}

Essentially I should be able to replicate this form of nesting via `ul`'s and `li`'s

**What do I have?**

I have built a react component mixin that does the following:

```
/**
 * Helps with abstracting certian logic from the comments component.
 */
var CommentsMixins = {

  commentElements: [],

  /**
   * Recursive fucntion to help get all nested comments.
   *
   * Keeps the order of the nested comments And renders a react component
   * which is a single comment.
   */
  renderComments: function(comments) {
    for (var key in comments) {
      if (key === 'children' && key.length !== 0) {
        var nestedComments = comments[key]
        for (var i = 0; i < nestedComments.length; i++) {
          this.commentElements.push('<li id="comment-'+nestedComments[i].id+'" class="indented"> <h1>'+nestedComments[i].author+' <small>said ... </small></h1>  <p>'+nestedComments[i].comment+'</p></li>');
          this.renderComments(nestedComments[i]);
        }
      }
  },

  getCommentElements: function() {
    return this.commentElements;
  }

}
```

This in turn will spit out:

```
<ul>
  <li> ... </li> <!-- id: 3 -->
  <li> ... </li> <!-- id: 4 -->
  <li> ... </li> <!-- id: 7 -->
  <li> ... </li> <!-- id: 5 -->
  ...
</ul>
```

When it should be something like:

```
<ul>
 <li> <!-- id: 3 -->
   <ul>
     <li> ... </li> <!-- id: 4 -->
   </ul>
 </li>
 ...
<ul>
```

What would I have to change in my recursive function to get that type of layout? (**Note**: You can assume the parent `ul` is already done rendered. All the `li`'s and their children and grandchildren and so on and so forth are rendered inside the outer most `<ul></ul>`)

Comment: @user2864740 Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build the *tree* recursively - don't output to a flat array!

Consider the following which uses jQuery because it makes DOM manipulation easier. If not using jQuery, create an element *tree* using other DOM manipulation as such will represent the desired output structure. (YMMV; the theory is sound with this approach, but it may contain bugs as written.)

The `comments` parameter is an array that represents the *current level* of of comments to process (this is `response.comments` for the top-level and `comment.children` for descendants). Unlike the original approach there is only *one* loop inside the function as it uses recursion to walk the JSON *tree* and convert it into a DOM *tree*, one level/branch at a time.

```
buildComments: function(comments) {
   // Return undefined if there are no comments to process;
   // alternatively, it /may/ be appropriate to return an empty UL.
   if (!comments || !comments.length) {
       return;
   }

   // Create the container UL for the comments in this level.
   var list = $('<ul>');
   for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) { // Don't use for..in for arrays
       var comment = comments[i];

       // Create an LI for each comment and add it to the container
       var item = $('<li>')
           .attr('id', "comment-" + comment.id);
       // Add the LI to the UL parent
       list.append(item);
       // Add appropriate content to the item LI
       item.append($('<h1>').text(comment.author));
       item.append($('<p>').text(comment.comment));

       // And then do the same for each child level of comments..
       var childrenList = this.buildComments(comment.children);
       if (childrenList) {
           // ..adding children (UL) container to the current item (LI)
           item.append(childrenList);
       }
   }
   // Return container to be used by caller
   return list;
},
```

And use it like so

```
var commentList = helper.buildComments(result.comments)
if (commentList) {
    $('#commentLocation').append(commentList);
}
```

If the top-level UL already exists, it may be desired to simply append the immediate (LI) children of the resulting (UL) element.. however, such is left as adaptation.

Comment: The entire concept while sound falls apart under the fact that comments is an object, children is a key ob that object with an array of objects that continue to nest in this fashion. so things like `comments.length` do not exist. hence the `(for key in comments){}` and the `key === 'children'` part.

Comment: @user3379926 Each comment is an objects, but `comments` (and `children`) is an *array* of comment objects; it is the array that represents each level and is iterated.